# Select option not preselected after validation using collection in formtastic field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm 90% sure I'm doing something obviously wrong here, but when I'm using a select with a collection:

```
<%= f.input :description, 
  :label => "Which best describes who you are?", 
  :prompt => "Select an option...", 
  :collection => [[ "I am working for a company", "working"],["I am a freelancer", "freelancer"],["I am studying", "studying"],["I have recently graduated", "graduated"],["I teach", "teach"],["None of these things","none"]] 
%>
```

and the form fails validation, the previously selected value is not selected, even though it is saved and is being passed to the params[:user][:description] as expected. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's described there https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/Deprecation-of-%3Aselected-option#what-to-do-instead, so following should work

```
f.select :description, 
         options_for_select([[ "I am working for a company", "working"],["I am a freelancer", "freelancer"],["I am studying", "studying"],["I have recently graduated", "graduated"],["I teach", "teach"],["None of these things","none"]], f.object.description)
         :label => "Which best describes who you are?", 
         :prompt => "Select an option...",
```

Also I would suggest moving collection to a separate helper method

Comment: Sorry that doesn't make a difference: the value is not preselected on reload

Comment: Afraid that still doesn't work. Super strange; not sure where I'm going wrong.